# reading specific columns from multiple csv files Nan values

Tags: python, csv

Im new to python i have an issue with reading one column from different csv files
this codes works but i gives me all NAN values. The column length is different in some of the csv files

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
def read_row(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, sep=r"\s+", usecols=[10])
files = glob('./*/*.csv')
df = pd.concat([read_row(fn) for fn in files], axis=1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked i just changed sep=r"\s+" to delimiter=','